# Prove that $(A∩B)^c = A^c ∪ B^c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I can barely solve this.

My attempt

Suppose $x ∈ (A∩B)^c$

$x ∉ (A ∩ B)$

$x ∉ A \ $  and $\  x ∉ B$

$x ∈(A∪B) - (A∩B) $

Comment: How did you jump to the last line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{split}x &\in (A \cap B)^c \\\iff x &\notin A \cap B \\\iff x &\notin A \text{ or } x \notin B\\\iff x&\in A^c \text{ or } x \in B^c\\\iff x &\in A^c \cup B^c\end{split}

Comment: why $x ∉ (A ∩ B)$ implies that  $x ∉ A \  or \  x ∉ B $ ?

Comment: For $x$ to be in the intersection of two sets it has to be in **both** of them. So for it not to be in the intersection, it means it is not in **at least one** of them.

Comment: Could you show the return ?

Comment: @hjx The argument follows backwards too. All statements are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, But clear up another thing, $x ∈ A^c ∪ B^c$, why does it implie that $X ∈ A^c \ or \  x ∈ B^c \ $. If x isn't both in A and B, the or means that X can't be in one of them or both.

Comment: An element belonging to to union of two sets means it belong to **at least one** of them. Just think of $A^c$ and $B^c$ as two sets. So, $x \in A^c \cup B^c$ implies that $x \in A^c$ **or** $x \in B^c.$

Comment: Thanks again, the concept of complement wasn't well understood by me.

Comment: No problem, I'll be happy to clear any more doubts.

Answer (score 2):

$\Rightarrow$ Let $x\in (A\cap B)^c$ then $x\notin A\cap B$ so $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$ or both. If $x\notin A$ then $x\in A^c$ so $x\in A^c\cup B^c$. Similarly, if $x\notin B$, then $x\in B^c$ so $x\in A^c\cup B^c$. Thus $(A\cap B)^c\subseteq A^c\cup B^c$.

$\Leftarrow$ Let $x\in A^c\cup B^c$ and assume $x\notin (A\cap B)^c$. If $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ then $x\notin A^c$ and $x\notin B^c$. However, that means $x\notin A^c\cup B^c$ which is a contradiction. Thus, $x\in (A\cap B)^c$ must be the case, so, $A^c\cup B^c = (A\cap B)^c$.